# Should I limit the amount of tokens a person can buy/sell per transaction/per 24 hours

Tags: tokens, smart-contract-wallets, binance

I'm creating a token and want to solve the big whale issue of pump and dump, or just the dump problem. As such, I thought about limiting how much an address can sell per transaction or per 24 hours. Is this possible in a Bep20 smart contract? And if it is, does this affect the amount a person can also buy?

Would there be unknown negative consequences of this type of restriction?

Lastly, Are there any tokens currently implementing this?

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 2):

Just limiting the sales per address won't solve the problem as whales will just become more sophisticated and split their funds up to many addresses over time. You can however use a protocol like [proof of humanity](https://www.proofofhumanity.id/) to check whether addresses are truly unique by having them linked to a unique identity and limit buys and sells like that.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot restrict "per person" unless your token requires identity verification on all addresses that touch the token.

Comment: Hi. Yeah, sorry my phrasing was wrong. I know a person can have many accounts on the one wallet/many wallets. I meant, will a sell limit also affect the amount a single address can buy? For example will the liquid pool only be able to sell so many to z address upon z address attempting to buy more than the sell limit?

Comment: There is no point limited how much a single address can buy because generating addresses is free. A liquidity pool can set up as many addresses as they wish.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't suspect a liquidity pool would use more than one address for each pairing. But that is good. It would mean a single address can buy as many tokens as they wish but cannot sell more than the smart contracts proposed limit . Limiting an addresses sell amount is more about putting an obstacle In the way/making it time consuming as apposed to completely restricting.